# Add in a where clause

Tags: razor, umbraco

I have this foreach function, but I need to add a where clause.

I have added a checkboxlist in Umbraco called "show"
Values if this is

```
"EN"
"SP"
"US"
...
```

Let us say I have checked EN and SP.

I only want a slide to be visible if the slide is Visible as now, and if the field `show` are "EN" is checked and true. How can i add this in my code?

```
@foreach (var Slider in Umbraco.ContentSingleAtXPath("//HomePage/SliderArea").Children.Where("Visible").OrderBy("CreateDate
desc").Take(4))
```

Comment: Which version umbraco?

Answer (score 0):

The code you have is using Dynamics and therefore you're restricted to using the pseudo-Linq extensions like `.Where("Visible")`.  You'll find it much easier to manipulate the list of items if you use the Typed objects instead.

Change this:

```
// Returns IPublishedContent as dynamic
Umbraco.ContentSingleAtXPath("//HomePage/SliderArea")
```

to this:

```
// Returns fully typed IPublishedContent
Umbraco.TypedContentSingleAtXPath("//HomePage/SliderArea")
```

Then you'll be able to use the full power of Linq to do this:

```
var area = Umbraco.TypedContentSingleAtXPath("//HomePage/SliderArea");

// returns a filtered IEnumerable<IPublishedContent>
var sliders = area.Children.Where(c => c.IsVisible() && c.GetPropertyValue<string>("show") == "EN");

@foreach (IPublishedContent slider in sliders.OrderByDescending(c => c.CreateDate).Take(4))
{
    // You can get the dynamic equivalent of the IPublishedContent like this if you wish:
    dynamic dSlider = slider.AsDynamic();
    // ...
}
```